# How to stub after_create callback save! in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, mocking

I receive following error:

Output:

```
1) LabelsController#create label is new creates a new label
   Failure/Error: post :create, attributes[:label], format: :json
   NoMethodError:
     undefined method `save!' for nil:NilClass
   # ./app/models/labeling.rb:17:in `update_target'
```

In Labeling model:

```
after_create :update_target

def update_target
   self.target.save!
end
```

Test:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe LabelsController do
  before(:each) do
    controller.stub(:current_user).and_return(mock_model(User))
    stub_request(:any, "www.example.com").to_return(status: 200)
  end
  describe "#create" do
    context "label is new" do
      it "creates a new label" do
        attributes = {
          label: {
            name: "test",
            labeling: {
              target_type: "Link", target_id: 1
            }
          }
        }
        response.status.should == 200
        post :create, attributes[:label], format: :json
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Labeling controller:

```
  def create
    label = Label.find_by_name(params[:name])

    labeling = label.labelings.build do |lb|
      lb.user_id     = current_user.id
      lb.target_type = params[:labeling][:target_type]
      lb.target_id   = params[:labeling][:target_id]
    end

    if labeling.save
      render json: {
        name: label.name,
        id: label.id,
        labeling: {
          id: labeling.id
        }
      }
    end
  end
```

Comment: And the controller create code please.

Comment: Just added whole controller action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it you don't have a Target with ID 1 on the database, so where you refer to `self.target` the returned value is nil.
What I'd do in your case is first create a target and then pass its id to the attributes hash:

```
target = Traget.create!
attributes = {
          label: {
            name: "test",
            labeling: {
              target_type: "Link", target_id: target.id
            }
          }
        }
```

This way you don't need to stub anything.
If you really must stub the method you can use RSpecs any_instance method:

```
Labeling.any_instance.stub(:update_target).and_return(true)
```

Comment: But I would like to avoid create Target.

Comment: Then you can use the second option I suggested. This one does not require to create a Target.

Comment: With the latest version of RSpec, the syntax is `allow_any_instance_of(MyClass).to receive(:my_method).and_return(true)`